# Determine number of buckets in hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two hive table with aproximatly equal volume.
Record Count(Aprox): 5779062484
Both table have 3 keys: loc_id(int), item_id(int), week_detail(string)
I am joining(inner join) both tables on basis of above keys, and result data is of same size. e.g. 5779062484
Total time to join is aprox. 3 Hours.
I am thinking to bucketize both table and then join to improve performance.
How many number of buckets and on which column I should use bucketing ?
I am only selecting data from both tables directly on the basis of inner join.
Also let me know can I use any specific settings in cluster to improve performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to keep in mind (based on my own experience):

- Don't make buckets to small, preferably bigger than the hdp block size (128mb in latest dist).
- This means if your item_id is in range 1-1000 you could have 1000 buckets of size ~5mb, this adds to the "hdp small file problem", so is not preferred. (In short: namenode will get a heavy burden when there are many small files in hdfs)
- According to this you should have around 40 buckets.
- You can also choose to bucket based on all your primary keys, but I don't know if there is an efficiency/speed improvement versus bucketing based on just one key. Maybe you could test that out. Very interested to hear the results. I think if you bucket on all the keys (with ~40 buckets) you will get the most speed improvement, but this is just a theoretical guess.
- For the settings I would turn Tez on. These are my options (or a multitude of this depending on cluster/node size): hive.tez.container.size=10240 --hiveconf hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx8192m

Sidenote: I would generally use Spark SQL for most Hive operations, but Spark still doesn't support bucketed nor transactional tables in current versions.

Comment: My join on two table got optimised with 32 buckets, but loading time of these two tables got increased as 32 reducers added on inserting. Is there any way or setting to optimise it too ?

Comment: You may find more about reducers, threads and parallel execution here: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/22419/hive-on-tez-performance-tuning-determining-reducer.html